# Change Google map marker Icon when user click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I am using *google map* and i placed some custom marker icons in google map. I need to change marker icon based on some condition.

Actually the marker icon changes is happening based on my condition but the new icon is not showing.Its overlapped with old icon

This is my code:

```
  var locationJson = result.invocationResult;// set off arry values from db      
        for (i = 0; i < locationJson.length; i++) {
    if (locationJson[i].buy== "YES") {     
                        markerimage = "images/buy.png";// First icon    
                    }     
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
                        position : latLng,     
                        map : map,    
                        icon : markerimage      
                    });       
                    markers[i]=marker;  
    if (locationJson[i].buy== "NO") {           
                        markerimage = "images/buy.png";  
                        markers[i].setIcon(markerimage);//changing icon        

                    }            
    }
```

This is the part of my code.How can i remove or change the old marker icon and replace new icon in that place?

Comment: why not first check var sold value then create marker and setIcon will work after the marker is drawn on map.

Comment: This is one part of the function .Initially i need the   `markerimage  = "images/sold.png"; ` the sold value change from user click on button. My question is how can i change the previous  marker icon with new marker icon???

Comment: after drawing the marker on map you want to change is it right,if so setIcon will work otherwise it won't.

Comment: Yes that i need , Actually the setIcon adding the new icon but its overlapped with previous one. How can we remove the previous marker and place new marker in same place??

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  There is something else going on, the code you have posted should work (perhaps you have this code inside a loop?).

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I just updated the example code

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing marker

```
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}
```

Then redraw Marker with new image

Comment: Hi Verma ,thanks for the reply can you please refer the above code i just updated my actual thing...